# ReactJS: How to properly link to a download file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `manual.pdf` file that I need to attach to my document.
The conventional wisdom would be to link the file source in the `href` attribute of an `<a>` tag:

```
<a href="../assets/img/manual.pdf" download>Manual</a>
```

React seems to not like it, I assume. **Failed-No file** error is given upon click on the `<a>` tag.

When it is an `<img>` tag with a local file, I would import the source `import logo from '../assets/img/logo.svg';`, then pass it to the `src` attribute like so `<img src={logo} alt="brand logo" />`.

- I tried it - no use.
- giving the absolute path - no use.
- giving a relative path - no use.

It seems that it does not work the same way with `<a>` tags.
How do I properly link local files in a React Project?

P.S. I have heard of React routes, but I am not linking to any page, it is for downloading a file.

Comment: I doubt React has anything to do with your "Failed-No file" error.

Comment: It could be. How would you go about linking a download file source to an a tag?

Comment: I would make sure the relative path to the file is actually correct. Are you using webpack or any other bundler? Also, if you paste the absolute path into your address bar, does the download start?

Comment: @codemonkey no it is a simple create-react-app app. The path is correct. trust me on that. Yes it does download the file if I just copy and paste the abs. path to the browser. putting that same path into the href attribute does not work

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<Link to="/files/manual.pdf" target="_blank" download>Download</Link>
```

Where `/files/manual.pdf` is inside your `public` folder

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link you mean this link? I have to download the react-router-dom first, right?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver (FileSaver.js)

```
//function for saving file
const saveManual = () => {
fileSaver.saveAs(
  process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_URL + "../assets/img/manual.pdf",
  "manual.pdf"
);
};

//button for calling 
<button onClick={saveManual}>
    Manual
</button>
```

Comment: Do I really need a separate package for a simple thing like that?

Comment: The way that I used.

Comment: I appreciate your effort. Thank you